# WKHTMLTOPDF -- Is possible to display dynamic headers?

Tags: php, dynamic, header, wkhtmltopdf

Im using wkhtmltopdf --header-html option, but it seems, that it really works only with html code. Is there any way I can add some PHP and force it to working somehow? I need to display Date and user´s e-mail on every page... Thanks for any advice ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can feed --header-html almost anything :) Try the following to see my point:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --margin-top 30mm --header-html isitchristmas.com google.fi x.pdf
```

So isitchristmas.com could be www.yoursite.com/magical/ponies.php

Just to add, you cant run the php files locally so you need a webserver to serve them. If you need 100% local dynamic headers you could try some fake dynamic with javascript; use `--header-html myheader.html?date=12345&usermail=derp` and then process the URL with javacript (I havent tried it).

Comment: Thanks! I didn´t realize it could be done this way :) I used URL parameters, but I didn´t need JS fortunately :)

Comment: Now how do you do this with local files instead of URLs?

Comment: @Mir You can just use local file paths instead of URLs, so if you are on windows the command would be like `wkhtmltopdf.exe --margin-top 30mm --header-html c:/HTML/myHeader.html c:/HTML/myPage.html c:/output/x.pdf`. You can use relative paths too, they don't have to be the full path.
`

Answer (score 2):

To add extra query string parameters for your header/footer html you need to use the command line switch 'replace'.

The wording of the help/manual is a little misleading (i.e. better wording would have cleared up the issue), as it lead me on the wrong path (tried using the 'post' switch). I found the solution after digging through the code on github.

Comment: An example of using the --replace switch would be nice.