# WKHTMLTOPDF Dynamic Header on every page

Tags: node.js, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to produce a PDF file using WKHTMLTOPDF library in NODE for a large HTML file. I need to be able to stuff in some content in the Header and Footer on every page. But the content on the header changes on every page for e.g, have custom numbering in a format like BX008761. The number should increment on every page.

First page will be BX008761, second page BX008762, third BX008763 so on..

I could find a thread which is related..

[WKHTMLTOPDF -- Is possible to display dynamic headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981853/wkhtmltopdf-is-possible-to-display-dynamic-headers)

the above thread states:
"**you can feed --header-html almost anything :) Try the following to see my point:**

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --margin-top 30mm --header-html isitchristmas.com google.fi x.pdf
```

**So isitchristmas.com could be www.yoursite.com/magical/ponies.php"**

does the source value provided for --header-html option be called for every page of the PDF rendered or it is called just once for every PDF..?

Appreciate your support.Thank you.

EDIT : I have tried a sample program and confirmed that it will process the value provided for --header-html option on every page rendered with in PDF. I am using a remote service to return the HTML string as a response to the url.

Now it is displaying the html string as is, instead of decoding it.

when the service returns below string:

**<html> <body> <span style="color:red" > 123 :: 0 :: 3000025 :: 634943551338828720</span> <body> <html>**

then the header on every page is also same as above instead of displaying the text in red color. how do i make the wkhtmltohtml understand that the content it received from service need to be decoded.

appreciate if any one can suggest a workaround.

Thank you.

EDIT : I have used another work around to return a HTML page for the header content. I used essentially a HTTPHandler in asp.net to return a valid response and the issue looks to have addressed the core issue of having a dynamic header on every page.

Comment: I'd recommend adding your edit as your own answer so people with the same problem can find this and quickly see your solution. If you're willing to write it out a little bit more. Also a post with no answer and (close to) no likes gets deleted if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: His question was about a dynamic header with WKHTMLTOPDF tool, not with asp.net which he says is his workaround. Therefore, the question is not yet answered.