# Wkhtmltopdf - How to display GET parameter passed into template on every page of multipage doc?

Tags: javascript, get, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have an application that generates PDF files.  So far it is able to use wkhtmltopdf to create multipage pdf files but so far I am not sure how to repeat dynamic content on a static html template that receives a query string parameter.

Is there any way in this context to pass in a query string parameter as a GET and view the parameter on all pages.

I have only been able to display the dynamic JavaScript based content on the first page only.

EDIT: I have found two related posts but am unsure how to proceed as I am still getting  the header on the first page only.

[WKHTMLTOPDF Dynamic Header on every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421591/wkhtmltopdf-dynamic-header-on-every-page)

[WKHTMLTOPDF -- Is possible to display dynamic headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981853/wkhtmltopdf-is-possible-to-display-dynamic-headers)

EDIT:  I have seen the header on some other pages including the first page but not all of the pages.   At this point I am unsure if this is a bug or if I am not processing the data correctly in the header template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template I was trying to pass data in to was the header file.  I solved the problem by not using a header file.  Instead, inside the main template loop (Razor) I embedded JavaScript to get executed each time in the loop in the main template.  I inserted new tables with header after breaking the page.  The header value contained a script code to output the header content dynamically to the  element.  When the loop inserted a page break I would close tag for the table on that page and insert a new opening table tag.

Each page now has separate tables giving me the desired header/content for each page.